# dask --preload 'Unknown argument specifier'

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, python-click

I'm trying to get `dask-scheduler` to preload an init file and I can't even get the example code from the `dask` docs to run.

`dask-scheduler` supposedly supports a `--preload` option which loads an arbitrary python file from disk and calls a `dask_setup` function in that file (https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#customizing-initialization).

Following the example in the docs (there is actually a typo in the example code in the docs, fixed code below), the file is loaded but I get an error saying

> Error: Unknown argument specified: %r Was click-configurable --preload target provided?

I can get `--preload` to work as long as I don't have extra `click` arguments for `dask_setup()`, the problem is that I need those extra arguments.

How do I get the example script to be "click-configurable"?

my environment is:

```
click==6.7, dask==0.17.1, distributed==1.21.1
```

---

```
# scheduler-setup.py
import click

from distributed.diagnostics.plugin import SchedulerPlugin

class MyPlugin(SchedulerPlugin):
    def __init__(self, print_count):
      self.print_count = print_count
      SchedulerPlugin.__init__(self)

    def add_worker(self, scheduler=None, worker=None, **kwargs):
        print("Added a new worker at:", worker)
        if self.print_count and scheduler is not None:
            print("Total workers:", len(scheduler.workers))

@click.command
@click.option("--print-count/--no-print-count", default=False)
def dask_setup(scheduler, print_count):
    plugin = MyPlugin(print_count)
    scheduler.add_plugin(plugin)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that was easy, `click.command` was missing `()`

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--print-count/--no-print-count", default=False)
def dask_setup(scheduler, print_count):
    plugin = MyPlugin(print_count)
    scheduler.add_plugin(plugin)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution.  Fixed in https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1784

Comment: @MRocklin meant to do a PR, but you beat me to it. You might want to fix the `SyntaxError` for the missing colon in the `if` in `add_worker` as well

Comment: I'll wait for you to do this one :)